# visual studio test explorer keyboard set focus to tests list

Tags: visual-studio

I find the focus always seems to end up in the output or summary and I can't find anyway to get to the tree view with the list of tests by the keyboard. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found pressing down arrow and then Shift+Tab seems to work.  It's pretty wonky.